# Laravel 5 route does not use method

Tags: laravel, controller, routes

I'm having an issue with route to my controller. Route does not use method which is defined in a controller.

This is my route:

```
Route::get('movie/{$id}', [
    'as' => 'getMovie',
    'uses' => 'MovieController@getMovie'
]);
```

That's the controller:

```
class MovieController extends Controller
{
    public function getMovie($id)
    {
        $movie = Tmdb::getMoviesApi()->getMovie($id);
        dd($movie);
    }
}
```

And last thing, the anchor tag

```
<a href="{{ Route('getMovie', $movie['id']) }}" data-toggle="movie-overview">
```

When i go into that link it gives me URL:
http://localhost/public/movie/395992
and error NotFoundHttpException

What's wrong with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the route to:

```
Route::get('movie/{id}', ....
```

Comment: Nice one mate! Cheers! I knew I missed something simple, it's my first application that I'm doing.